# ibuffer : no filters in effect

Tags: ibuffer

I use `ibuffer` with emacs `30.0.50-2b8ab57b` on Windows 11.

It used to work well with this configuration :

```
(require 'ibuffer)

(setq-default ibuffer-default-sorting-mode 'major-mode)

(setq ibuffer-show-empty-filter-groups nil)

;; Use human readable Size column instead of original one
(define-ibuffer-column size-h
  (:name "Size" :inline t)
  (cond
   ((> (buffer-size) 1000000) (format "%7.1fM" (/ (buffer-size) 1000000.0)))
   ((> (buffer-size) 100000) (format "%7.0fk" (/ (buffer-size) 1000.0)))
   ((> (buffer-size) 1000) (format "%7.1fk" (/ (buffer-size) 1000.0)))
   (t (format "%8d" (buffer-size)))))

;; Modify the default ibuffer-formats
(setq ibuffer-formats
      '((mark modified read-only " "
              (name 40 40 :left :elide)
              " "
              (size-h 9 -1 :right)
              " "
              (mode 16 16 :left :elide)
              " "
              filename-and-process)))
(setq ibuffer-filter-group-name-face 'font-lock-doc-face)

(require 'ibuf-ext)

(setq ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
      (quote (("default"
               ("terminal"  (or
                             (mode . term-mode)
                             (mode . shell-mode)
                             (mode . eshell-mode)))
               ("erc" (predicate string-match "ERC" mode-name))
               ("emacs" (or
                         (name . "^\\*scratch\\*$")
                         (name . "^\\*Messages\\*$")))
               ("gnus" (or
                        (mode . message-mode)
                        (mode . bbdb-mode)
                        (mode . mail-mode)
                        (mode . gnus-group-mode)
                        (mode . gnus-summary-mode)
                        (mode . gnus-article-mode)
                        (name . "^\\.bbdb$")
                        (name . "^\\.newsrc-dribble")
                        (name . "^bbdb\\.el$")
                        (name . "^newsrc\\.eld$")
                        (name . "^newsrc-dribble$")
                        (name . "^bbdb$")
                        (name . "^\\*BBDB\\*$")))
               ("java" (name . "\\.java/?.*$"))
               ("javascript" (name . "\\.js/?.*$"))
               ("python" (name . "\\.py/?.*$"))
               ("xml" (name . "\\.xml/?.*$"))
               ("lua" (name . "\\.lua/?.*$"))
               ("elisp" (name . "\\.el/?.*$"))
               ("tex" (name . "\\.tex/?.*$"))
               ("bib" (name . "\\.bib/?.*$"))
               ("pdf" (name . "\\.pdf/?.*$"))
               ("image" (name . "\\.png/?.*$\\|\\.jpg/?.*$\\|\\.svg/?.*$"))
               ("org" (mode . org-mode))
               ("agenda" (name . "^\\*Org Agenda\\*$"))
               ("bash" (or
                         (predicate string-match "Shell-script" mode-name)
                         (mode . shell-script-mode)
                         (mode . sh-mode)))
               ("pwsh" (mode . powershell-mode))
               ("dired" (mode . dired-mode))
               ("sidebar" (predicate string-match "Dired-sidebar" mode-name))
               ("debug" (name . "^\\*localhost([0-9]+)[^\\*]+\\*$"))
               ("special" (name . "^\\*[^\\*]+\\*$"))))))

(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (ibuffer-auto-mode 1)
            (ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "default")))

(use-package all-the-icons-ibuffer
  :config
  (setq all-the-icons-ibuffer-icon t
        all-the-icons-ibuffer-color-icon t
        all-the-icons-ibuffer-icon-size 1.0
        all-the-icons-ibuffer-icon-v-adjust 0.0
        all-the-icons-ibuffer-human-readable-size t)
  :hook (ibuffer-mode . all-the-icons-ibuffer-mode))
```

Since a few weeks, I regularly run into the error "No filters in effect".

The step to reproduce this is for example to open some org files and then
open one elisp file. As soon as the elisp file is opened, `ibuffer` does not
work any more and returns "No filters in effect".

Then, if I kill the elisp buffer, `ibuffer` works again well.

This can also happen with some other buffers. To solve the issue, I
have no other choice but to kill buffers until the ones causing this error
disappear.

I googled this error without any much success. Do you have an idea of what is going
wrong with my configuration ?